# How to get the current state of the tablet

Tags: nao-robot, pepper, choregraphe

Is there a way to get the current state of the tablet - if it is in sleep mode, in screen saver mode or if a picture is loaded - to get the name of the loaded picture for example. I didn't find anything in [ALTabletService API](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-4/naoqi/core/altabletservice-api.html#ALTabletService::loadApplication__ssCR), but judging on `ALTabletService::resetTablet()` - `Reset the tablet as if no one used it before, i.e. clean the stack of activities, the web browser content, and the web browser cache.` there  is a stack of tablet activities and perhaps there is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can actually do that. You have to assume it's doing the right thing. If you need to check if your webview is loaded properly, why not raising an Event every 15s from the javascript and subscribe to it from Python? then as soon as Python does not receive this event for 15s, it can reload the page !